# PrintInfo() Giving Me A Hard Time

Tags: c++, class

So I'm studying with classes and and I'm making a program that prints user entered data, however I can't seem to get past this one compiler error. The gist of the program is to take student user data and output it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;


class Student {
    
    public:
        Student();
        ~Student();
        void SetName(string studentname); //mutator for name
        void SetId(int studentid); //mutator for id
        void SetGender(string studentgender); //mutator for gender 
        void SetEthnicity(string studentethnicity); // mutator for ethnicity 
        void SetMajor(string studentmajor); //mutator for major 
        void SetMinor(string studentminor); //mutator for minor 
        void SetGPA(float studentgpa); // mutator for gpa
        string GetName(); //accessor for name 
        int GetId(); //accessor for id 
        string GetGender(); //accesor for gender 
        string GetEthnicity(); // accessor for ethnicity 
        string GetMajor(); // accessor for major 
        string GetMinor(); //accessor for minor 
        float GetGPA(); // accessor for GPA
        void PrintInfo(void); // print student information
        
        
    private:
        string Name;
        int id_number;
        string gender;
        string ethnicity;
        string major;
        string minor;
        float gpa;
        
        
        
};  


Student::Student()
{
    Name = "   ";
    id_number = 0;
    gender = " ";
    ethnicity = " ";
    major = " ";
    minor = "None";
    gpa = 0;
}

//mutator functions
void Student::SetName(string studentname)
    {
        Name = studentname;
    };
void Student::SetId(int studentid)  
{
    id_number = studentid;
}
void Student::SetGender(string studentgender)
{
    gender = studentgender;
}
void Student::SetEthnicity(string studentethnicity)
{
    ethnicity = studentethnicity;
}
void Student::SetMajor(string studentmajor)
{
    major = studentmajor;
}
void Student::SetMinor(string studentminor)
{
    minor = studentminor;
}
void Student::SetGPA(float studentgpa)
{
    gpa = studentgpa;
}

//accessor functions 

string Student::GetName()
{
    return Name;
}
int Student::GetId()
{
    return id_number;
}
string Student::GetGender()
{
    return gender;
}
string Student::GetEthnicity()
{
    return ethnicity;
}
string Student::GetMajor()
{
    return major;
}
string Student::GetMinor()
{
    return minor;
}
float Student::GetGPA()
{
    return gpa;
}

void Student::PrintInfo(void)
{
    cout<<"Name: "<<myStudent.GetName()<<endl;
    cout<<"ID #: "<<myStudent.GetId()<<endl;
    cout<<"Gender: "<<myStudent.GetGender()<<endl;
    cout<<"Ethnicity: "<<myStudent.GetEthnicity()<<endl;
    cout<<"Major: "<<myStudent.GetMajor()<<endl;
    cout<<"Minor: "<<myStudent.GetMinor()<<endl;
    cout<<"GPA: "<<myStudent.GetGPA()<<endl;
    
}

int main()
{
    
    int* studentarray;
    studentarray = new int[5];
    
    Student myStudent;

    string names;
    int ids;
    string genders;
    string ethnicities;
    string majors;
    string minors;
    float gpas;
    
    cout<<"Student Information."<<endl;
    
    cout<<"Name: "<<endl;
    getline (cin, names);
    
    cout<<"ID Number: "<<endl;
    cin>> ids;
    
    cout<<"Gender: "<<endl;
    getline(cin, genders);
    
    cout<<"Ethnicity: "<<endl;
    getline(cin, ethnicities);
    
    cout<<"Major: "<<endl;
    getline(cin, majors);
    
    cout<<"Minor: "<<endl;
    getline(cin, minors);
    
    cout<<"Enter GPA: "<<endl;
    cin>> gpas;
    
    myStudent.SetName(names);
    myStudent.SetId(ids);
    myStudent.SetGender(genders);
    myStudent.SetEthnicity(ethnicities);
    myStudent.SetMajor(majors);
    myStudent.SetMinor(minors);
    myStudent.SetGPA(gpas);
    
    
    myStudent.PrintInfo();
    
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Then this is my compiler error

In member function 'void Student::PrintInfo()':
117:18: error: 'myStudent' was not declared in this scope

Comment: It means exactly what it says - `myStudent` is not a thing inside the `Student::PrintInfo()`

Comment: You want to fix this exactly as the answer states.  In addition you probably also should spend a some time  and read about variable scope. `myStudent` exists inside of `int main()` and no where else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myStudent` does not exist inside `Student::PrintInfo()`.

`PrintInfo()` is actually a member function, so it should look simply like this.

```
void Student::PrintInfo(void)
{
    cout<<"Name: "<< GetName()<<endl;
    cout<<"ID #: "<< GetId()<<endl;
    cout<<"Gender: "<< GetGender()<<endl;
    cout<<"Ethnicity: "<< GetEthnicity()<<endl;
    cout<<"Major: "<< GetMajor()<<endl;
    cout<<"Minor: "<< GetMinor()<<endl;
    cout<<"GPA: "<< GetGPA()<<endl;
}
```

This one is even better (Edit: Better *in this case*. If the getter methods were to perform a more complex task than just retrieve the value, you would use them):

```
void Student::PrintInfo(void)
{
    cout<<"Name: "<< Name<<endl;
    cout<<"ID #: "<< id_number<<endl;
    cout<<"Gender: "<< gender<<endl;
    cout<<"Ethnicity: "<< ethnicity<<endl;
    cout<<"Major: "<< major<<endl;
    cout<<"Minor: "<< minor<<endl;
    cout<<"GPA: "<< gpa<<endl;
}
```

Or, for clarity, you might prefer this format:

```
void Student::PrintInfo(void)
{
    cout<<"Name: "<< this->Name<<endl;
    cout<<"ID #: "<< this->id_number<<endl;
    cout<<"Gender: "<< this->gender<<endl;
    cout<<"Ethnicity: "<< this->ethnicity<<endl;
    cout<<"Major: "<< this->major<<endl;
    cout<<"Minor: "<< this->minor<<endl;
    cout<<"GPA: "<< this->gpa<<endl;
}
```

As a side note, you should specify that your getter methods (and `PrintInfo` as well) don't modify the object.

```
int GetWhatever() const {} // <-- The const keyword right there
```

Comment: not using the getters is not necessarily "better". Consider eg the possibility of `gender` being an enum internally, while `GetGender` can return a string